font is not rendering the glyph in html, although supported by it
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+Devanagari:wght@100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Hello World</title>
    <style>
    @charset "UTF-8";
    @font-face {
      font-family: ff1;
      src: url('css/fonts/ff1.ttf');
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    .noto {
      font-family: "Noto Sans Devanagari", sans-serif;
      font-optical-sizing: auto;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-style: normal;
      font-variation-settings:
        "wdth" 100;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<span style="font-family:ff1;font-size:20px;">ff1 = आमाएं</span>
</br>
<span class="noto">noto = आमाएं<span>
</body>
</html>


Download custom font ff1.zip
Why Noto is not rendering the glyph properly? It's supported by it. I have tried other Devanagari fonts but none of them is able to render the text correctly.

"Download custom font ff1.ttf" Mmmm, no thanks

Are you sure you the encoding of  the text is standard compliant? From my research the missing character at unicode point UE00C is in the PUA and not included in standard Devangari range U+0900..U+097F

I have downloaded the font and the text data from a website and I strongly believe that the text is custom font compliant. The problem is not just with one but many glyph characters. Doing some tests to make sure that's the cause. If yes, how do i resolve the problem, I have to convert huge amount of data.
